# Why did my MacBook Pro wake from sleep without requiring my password?

Tags: mac, security, sleep, password-protection

I have set in System Preferences to `Require password 5 seconds after sleep or screen saver begins`:

[image: System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General]

Earlier today, I opened the lid of my MacBook Pro and the screen illuminated and showed my desktop without requiring my password. This alarmed me. Shortly thereafter, I opened Console.app and copied the data from the following sources ("highlighted" in the left pane in the following image) by selecting a source, then selecting the log data pane, pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, and then pasting into a text file and saving. I repeated for each source.

[image: Console.app]

I saw that the computer was actually asleep because there was a ~7 hour break in `system.log`. The only potentially relevant messages I saw in  that log were these—the first of which occurred ~22s after the log break:

```
Feb 19 15:02:25 device com.apple.preference.security.remoteservice[8086]: objc[8086]: Class AWDSecurityPrefAutoUnlockSetup is implemented in both /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Security.prefPane/Contents/XPCServices/com.apple.preference.security.remoteservice.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.preference.security.remoteservice (0x10b7678e8) and /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Security.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/Security (0x10b9fe020). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Feb 19 15:02:30 device com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.preference.security.remoteservice[8086]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by com.apple.preference.security.re[8086]
```

Here is the hardware overview for my MacBook Pro:

```
Model Name:            MacBook Pro
Model Identifier:      MacBookPro11,3
Processor Name:        Intel Core i7
Processor Speed:       2.5 GHz
Number of Processors:  1
Total Number of Cores: 4
L2 Cache (per Core):   256 KB
L3 Cache:              6 MB
Memory:                16 GB
Boot ROM Version:      MBP112.0138.B21
SMC Version (system):  2.19f12
macOS Version:         10.12.3 (16D32)
```

**What caused this security compromise?**

Comment: @Mods: If you think I'm more likely to get the answer on Security.SE, please migrate. I thought it would be more likely to be seen here and it does fit the scope.

Comment: Is [PowerNap](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204032) set?

Comment: @JanDoggen Yes for plugged in power, No for battery. It was not plugged in since the console break.